# Can CVE-2023-33953 be solved by limiting the length of the HTTP header on an earlier version? currently i am using gRPC 1.0.0

Tags: grpc, cve

I am using gRPC 1.0.0(C), and came across this vulnerability CVE-2023-33953, however i cant upgrade to latest gRPC yet.
is there a way to solve this in gRPC, 1.0.0 which is mostly C based?

tried solution mentioned in this ticket
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/34251

but it introduces other problems like CVE-2023-32731